# Is there a way to shutdown mac when screen is turned off?

Tags: mac-mini, power-management

I have a mac mini, which is connected to a TV using HDMI cable. TV & mini are connected to separate power source, so that I can shutdown TV and mini independently as required.

Primary use of mini is a media center and i watch lot of online videos over it.

The problem is sometime, if i switch off the TV, online videos continue to play in the computer and thus consuming bandwidth. So i'm looking for a way to shutdown (close my video player application etc.) mini if the TV display goes off.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5831557/shut-down-or-reboot-your-mac-immediately-with-a-keyboard-command

Comment: It'll tell you how to shut down your mac using a keybaord command. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there some impediment to powering up the TV again, shutting down the mini, and then powering down the TV? If you want a good remote Mac screen control app for your iPhone/iPad, try Screens: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-access-your-computer/id655890150?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd> followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> will shut down your computer. No monitor necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any way of doing this without 3rd party software, because there are no built-in ways that I am aware of to check to see if the screen is off.

However, this can be done fairly easily with [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) using the [conditional](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/6/calculations.html) `SCREENSAVER()` which *is* smart enough to tell if either:

1. The screensaver of the Mac is turned ON
2. The screen of the Mac is turned OFF

I also added a check to make sure that the Mac has been idle for at least 5 minutes (300 seconds) using another [conditional](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/6/calculations.html): `IDLE() > 300`. If you do not wish to keep that check, it can be removed by clicking the "-" next to it.

Since the OP did not say which application(s) s/he is using to watch video, I just used [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) as an example, but the macro can easily be adapted to quit any application(s), or run AppleScript, or a shell script, etc.

Here's what the macro looks like in Keyboard Maestro:

[image]

And here's a download link for [Quit-VLC-on-IDLE.kmmacros](https://raw.github.com/tjluoma/km-quit-vlc-on-idle/master/Quit-VLC-on-IDLE.kmmacros) (control+click = save link as…)

[View this information on Github](https://github.com/tjluoma/km-quit-vlc-on-idle)

Answer (score 0):

You could enable hibernation and let it auto sleep via Energy Saver settings. That effectively means the system is fully powered off when sleeping, but can be easily woken and will automatically sleep when not in use.

First, make sure it's sleeping at appropriate times via Energy Saver in System Preferences. Note that adjustments to Energy Saver settings may reset the hibernate mode, so you'll want to set up any other options *first*.

You can then use the `pmset` command (from the Terminal) to adjust the hibernate mode.

There are three recommended hibernate modes (none are supported except the default).

- 0 = basic sleep, memory stays in RAM only
- 3 = portable sleep, memory backed up to hibernate file, RAM is kept powered for a fast resume, but if power runs out the hibernate file can be used to resume
- 25 = hibernate only, memory backed up to hibernate file and RAM powered down

You can adjust the hibernate mode as follows (this sets it to the 3rd option):

```
# sudo pmset hibernatemode 25
```

And you can check its status via:

```
# pmset -g
```

Which will list all the power management settings (look for `hibernatemode` in the list to see how it's set). You'll want to check that after you adjust any Energy Saver settings, or install OS X updates.

Answer (score 0):

May be I got it totally wrong, but you are watching a video and then you shutdown your TV? And then you expect that the computer gets notification and stops the video playback?

Why do you not stop the video before the shutdown of the TV?

Or - if you want to shutdown your MacMini and TV: there a several media centers which offer a (remote controlled) shutdown of the computer. The TV should recognize that the MacMini is off and fall asleep too.